# What is the best(more fast) way to do replace in xslt

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

What is the best(more fast) way to do replace in xslt?

**1/ With Template**

```
  <xsl:template name="str-replace">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
        <xsl:call-template name="str-replace">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

**2/ With Extension Object**

```
public class ToolBox
{
        public string replace(string s, string el, string by)
        {return s.Replace(el, by);}
}

<xsl:value-of select="toolbox:replace($foo,$bar, $fobar)" />
```

Comment: Your `replace` function adds nothing over directly calling `String.Replace`.

Comment: Exact but it is not the question....

Comment: hence it was not posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance questions depend on knowing what product you are using. The native code will almost certainly be faster, but on some processors the overhead of calling an extension function is high. So measure it.

Or switch to XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answser your question, I expect the string manipulation method to outperform the XML manipulation due to it not having to parse the XML document.

However, you should consider whether you want your replacement to be sensitive to the XML nature of the document or not. I.e. do you simply want to:

1. Alter the text of the document, replacing one string with another, irrespective of whether this occurs in an element name, text node, comment, &c. A string replacement, if not carefully controlled, could also result in an invalid resultant document, e.g. a string replacement of `<hello>` to `<there>` would alter a starting `<hello>` element but not the closing, `</there>` element.
2. Alter the XML in an context sensitive manner, allowing precise changes to particular elements, attributes or texts, without destroying the document structure.

Comment: As I understood the suggestion, it was not to use replace() on the unparsed lexical XML, but to call out from XSLT to an extension function that uses replace() on a text node. But I might have interpreted it wrongly!